# 'question eligible for bounty since 1 hour ago' but I don't see the 'start a bounty' button.

Tags: support, reputation, bounty, privileges

[**Edit**: It is my mistake, see the answer]

I posted this question [Polarization formula.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481167/polarization-formula) a bit more then 48hours ago. I reached the cap of the 75 points to give bounty.
I want to start a bounty on this question. Just below to the question I see 'question eligible for bounty since 1 hour ago' but the 'start a bounty' does not appear. It is really weird since on other questions I asked (*e.g.* [Motivation for the study of amoebas.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471062/motivations-for-the-study-of-amoebas)) the 'start a bounty' button appear.

I don't understand the problem.

**Edit:** related question: [Where is the bounty button?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34733/where-is-the-bounty-button)

Comment: Since you know the answer already, you might post an answer to your own question. Perhaps you might add link to this meta.SO post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34733/where-is-the-bounty-button

Answer (score 2):

I had 'answered' to the question, so I need to spend at least 100 rep points to give a bounty. And I did not have these 100 points already.